# Definition of vague convergence of distibution functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading Kai Lai Chung's A Course in Probability Theory. I understood the concept of vague convergence of a sequence of probability measures in the book. But it seems to me the book uses the concept of vague convergence of a sequence of distribution functions without defining it first. But I could miss the definition, and if you can point me where the book defines it, it will be nice.

So I was wondering

1. how the vague convergence of a
   sequence of distribution functions
   is defined?
2. how it is related to the vague
   convergence of the corresponding
   probability measures?
3. how it is related to the point-wise
   convergence of the distribution
   functions?
4. **ADDED**: for a sequence of
   (sub)probability measures or a
   sequence of distribution functions,
   how weak convergence is defined? How it and vague
   convergence are different from each
   other?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: It is defined, on p. 89: "We say that $F_n$ converges vaguely to $F$ and write..."

Comment: @Shai: Thanks! That answered my questions 1 and 2. Do you know for a sequence of (sub)probability measures or a sequence of distribution functions, how weak convergence is defined and how it and vague convergence are different from each other?

Comment: As for 4), weak convergence is the same as convergence in distribution. That is, a sequence of distribution functions $F_n$ converges to $F$ weakly if and only if $F_n (x) \to F(x)$ for any continuity point $x$ of $F$.

Comment: For the relation between different types of convergence of distribution functions, see pp. 9-10 in http://neptune.galaxy.gmu.edu/stats/syllabi/it971/Lecture7.pdf (if $F$ is proper then the definitions are equivalent).